# 2.45 GHz frequency generation

Tags: oscillator, microwave

I have designed RF-PA and to test the circuit, I want to design an oscillator which can give me a 2.45 GHz continuous wave. What are the simplest ways to design such a circuit? What are the requirement or the design procedure?

Comment: You can use a VCO like the MAX2753

Comment: You'll want controlled output power, so you can characterize the RF_PA's power gain. You'll want low output distortion, so you can characterize the RF_PA's distortion. Also your Zout should be 50_ohm, or controllable, so you can explore the instability of your PA, given arbitrary Z_source. (you'll also want to explore how reactive loads, on your PA, may cause oscillation). Thus............I'd consider a professional RF generator.

Comment: How specific are your needs? Most 2.4 GHz "digital" Radio ICs can do this at least approximately, as generating a CW signal is a requirement for regulatory testing.  It would be well documented how to do it with something like an NRF24L01, variably well documented for various BTLE SoCs.  Once you get into WiFi chips/modules it may be documented or it may be in a suite of tools that are hard to get from the vendor.  Of course all of these tend to have the accuracy, stability, and output characteristics they need for their purposes, which may not match your purposes.

Comment: For primary testing I just need 2.45 GHz CW with at least of 70 mW power output.